# How to host a file located in ~/ with nginx via nix on a nixos-server?

Tags: linux, nginx, nix, nixos

In my previous nixos server install, the answer suggested in this [article](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/slowly-going-crazy-trying-to-get-nginx-to-not-return-a-403-error/11964)
like adding `systemd.services.nginx.serviceConfig.ProtectHome = "read-only";` to my config worked for me, but isn't working on my current install.

```
 - system: `"x86_64-linux"`
 - host os: `Linux 5.15.59, NixOS, 22.11 (Raccoon), 22.11pre398667.39d7f929fbc`
 - multi-user?: `yes`
 - sandbox: `yes`
 - version: `nix-env (Nix) 2.10.3`
 - channels(root): `"nixos-22.11pre398667.39d7f929fbc"`
 - nixpkgs: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos`
```

I want to host files placed from my user's `~/` so I could easly update/edit files without root privileges.

Comment: The Question does not provide enough information to find the actual problem. Please provide your nix configuration and make clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend hosting the file in `/var/www` (or whatever the default path for hosting is in your distro, if this even changes between distros), create an nginx group and add the user nginx to this group (if there isn't one already), change the group ownership of the files in `/var/www` to nginx, and then add your user to the nginx group.

Answer (score 0):

`Okay, nginx can read from /var so my workaround is to use /var/www/website and ln -s /var/www/website ~/website .`

*quoting from [discourse.nixos.org](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/slowly-going-crazy-trying-to-get-nginx-to-not-return-a-403-error/11964)